# How do I make my CSS grid responsive and fills up my full container?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a problem right now with my grid that leaves this blank space on the sides (circled in red):
[image]

It becomes even worse when I make the screen size smaller and the grid reformats itself:
[image]

I want it so all my elements span the full width of my container and fill up this empty space so it'll be in line with my search bar. In other words, I don't want this extra space on both sides of my grid:
[image]

This is my CSS grid code.

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    gap: 2.5rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(226px, 360px)); */
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 226px);
}
```

As you can see I also tried the commented out line, but that doesn't work either. I also tried `auto-fit` instead, but it also doesn't do anything. And I tried `width: 100%` as well as `gap: auto` but neither of them work. How do I fill up this space with my grid? Below is a snippet with the same problem.

```css
.full-card {
    background-color: #6a90c9;
    width: 226px;
    height: 289px;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    gap: 2.5rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(226px, 360px)); */
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 226px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="padding: 50px;">       
  <div class="grid">

            <div class="full-card">
            </div>
           <div class="full-card">
            </div>
           <div class="full-card">
            </div>
           <div class="full-card">
            </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.grid {
    display: grid;
    gap: 2.5rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 226px);
}
.search {
  wisth: 100%;
  mergin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
  <div class="grid">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/250" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/250" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/250" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/250" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem, but then it brings another problem, there's a huge gap in the center whenever I resize my window. Also when I'm on mobile when it's one column, it has all the spacing to the right instead of the center.

Comment: You set fixed weight to columns, so there must be some empty space

Comment: So for mobile view I'll just reset it to center then? Right now it's left's aligned using space-between on mobile view with a huge space to the right.